# Accidentally deleted Android layout file

Tags: android

I accidentally deleted a layout file from my Android project. Is there any way I can get it back? I haven't touched since it was done. And I don't have copies of the file else where.

Comment: Right click on project and click on Restore from local History

Comment: I tried that but my file wasn't in Eclipse history anymore unfortunately.

Comment: @Sonali8890 +1 for good suggestion

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have the apk in your bin folder, you're lucky: use [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) and get your **decompiled** xml files back.
And, for the future, **always make backups**, as keyboardsurfer pointed out.

Comment: Thanks to your answer and the work of apktool, I've retrieved my layout file intact. Thanks a million.

Comment: I'm glad to have contributed to your next successful application! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your `Project`, hover on `Local History` and select `Show History`.
See changes and try to `revert`.

Answer (score -3):

Simple answer will be "no". You can not recover a file which is deleted by eclipse.