# Deleted layout file in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I accidentally deleted an important file from my android project in the layout folder..Can I get it back somehow?

I saw this post [Accidentally deleted Android layout file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628156/accidentally-deleted-android-layout-file) but since that was Eclipse I figured the solution might not be the same. I have the apk in bin.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin Studio @Jason